# how to reorder manually a dot graph with interfaz, no by coding

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have a graph in .dot format and I can view it in graphviz.

I would like to reorder the graph manually without modifying the dot code.

I aim to clarify the graph, not changing the hierarchy, but making it more beautiful.

Is there any program/interfaz to make it?

Or graphviz has any option to reorder it automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is the tool called [`nop`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/nop.1.pdf) which does pretty-print graphs. This is automatic and there is no interface.

Comment: as I see, is with command but I use graphviz in Windows. Is it possible to use here also? thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes this tool is in the same folder (/bin) as the other graph is tools.